# Не удалось вставить значение null в столбец Id, когда Id в экземпляре не равно null (EntityFramework 6, Code-first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Делаю взаимодействие с базой данных через службу wcf с помощью Entity framework И подход Code first. Все запросы к базе обрабатываются нормально, кроме INSERT (`dbContext.Users.Add()`):

[image: Картинка исключения]

На самом деле я объявляю Id != null, сервер тоже получает != null, поэтому я не понимаю почему null. Хотел посмотреть через SQL Profiler, Но он не подключается.

[image: Картинка объявления]

Ошибка сама по себе очень странная.

Объявление Id в базе
[image: Картинка объявления в базе]

User
[image: User]

Запрос, сформированный EntityFramework:

[image: Скриншот запроса]

Comment: А я вот верю базе данных: пишет, что был null, значит был null. В показанном коде какое значение у `lastId`?

Comment: _На самом деле я объявляю Id != null_ - покажите код определения сущности `User`: как именно задано `NOT NULL`. _сервер тоже получает != null_ - как это определили?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В тестовых данных lastId = 8

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ID это long, он не null в любом случае; Определил с помощью отладки (тестил на локальной машине)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Если я пробую вставить те же значения через ssms то они добавляются

Comment: Используйте свойство [Database.Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log(v=vs.113).aspx) и [посмотрите](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception), какой именно sql-запрос генерируется, какие параметры уходят в БД (выложите результат).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Обновил вопрос, выложил скриншот. Не понимаю, но видимо запрос не правильно формируется.

Comment: Недавно столкнулся с такой же ситуацией, из БД через EF нормально получаю данные, а новые добавить не получается. Поискал в сети, ответа почему это происходит не нашел. Начал эксперименты и обнаружил, что если установить свойство context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false, то новые объекты в БД сохраняются.  Возможно и тебе это поможет. Если кто знает ответ, почему так происходит - пишите, не  стесняйтесь.